# How to get the number of Google search result using PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying hard to find a way to get the number of Google search results using PHP? I have search Google and stackoverflow but have not found anything suitable.

I want to know how can I do this using PHP.

Comment: Please check.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055197/how-to-get-all-google-search-results-using-api

Answer (score 1):

When not using APIs:

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/search?q=test');
preg_match('/<div class="sd" id="resultStats">.*?([0-9\.\,]+).*?<\/div>/', $content, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Although i would advise against this way of (automated) queries.

Comment: This way is the best & easy.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse google search page.
in the return page, there has number of google search result .
such as,
when we search `stackoverflow` in google search box, these text will appear under google search box:
About 34,800,000 results (0.79 seconds)

Comment: Actually, The Google Web Search API is officially deprecated as of November 1, 2010.

Comment: Actually, [The Google Web Search API is officially deprecated as of November 1, 2010](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/
). so the way offer by Brijesh Khatri may fail.