# Output Google Search Results Using PHP?

Tags: php, search

I have looked at several old answers on stackoverflow but they are all out-dated and the API they used is no longer available.

I have created a JSON/Atom API, CX key and used a script Thanks to Adam Fischer I found on here but when I'm trying am now able to output print the results on the page I'm getting with the error:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$responseData in
>   E:\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP Training\google.php on line 19
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP
>   Training\google.php on line 19

This is what I have so far. below code.

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[MY API KEY]&cx=[MY CX KEY]&q=lecture';

$body = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($body);

for($x=0;$x<countif ($json->responseData->results);$x++>items){

echo "<b>Result ".($x+1)."</b>";
echo "<br>URL: ";
echoforeach ($json->responseData->results[$x]->url;
echo>items "<br>VisibleURL:as ";$item){
echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->visibleUrl;
echo "<br>Title: ";
echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->title;
echo "<br>Content: ";print_r($item)
echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->content;
echo "<br><br>"; }
}
```

The API is working correctly because when I visit This spits out everything in an array. Example: dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47731225/sample.txt

I'm trying to make the $url I see results such as be displayed on my page like a Google Search, for example: prntscr.com/drum5u

```
{
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "The Tank, Haydon Allen Lecture Theatre, Building 23, ANU",
   "htmlTitle": "The Tank, Haydon Allen \u003cb\u003eLecture\u003c/b\u003e Theatre, Building 23, ANU",
   "link": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid=1YGFZHcZ20jPvy5OiaKT1voy841Q&hl=en",
   "displayLink": "www.google.com",
   "snippet": "\"The Tank\", Haydon Allen Lecture Theatre, Building 23, The Australian National \nUniversity (ANU), Canberra, Australia.",
   "htmlSnippet": "&quot;The Tank&quot;, Haydon Allen \u003cb\u003eLecture\u003c/b\u003e Theatre, Building 23, The Australian National \u003cbr\u003e\nUniversity (ANU), Canberra, Australia.",
   "cacheId": "hTeucZ5TewoJ",
   "formattedUrl": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid...hl=en",
   "htmlFormattedUrl": "https://www.google.com/mymaps/viewer?mid...hl=en",
   "pagemap": {
    "cse_thumbnail": [
     {
      "width": "221",
      "height": "228",
      "src": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSntx5YhQgJQeJ6RAZajOx7SGOwh0oUu8jtpY6VOAS75V_oNkiXx923ro4"
     }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055197/how-to-get-all-google-search-results-using-api

Comment: Once you create a question, offer a bounty and then get a response you acknowledge as correct, don't change the question to a new one. Accept the helpful answer if correct (or flag why it's not correct) and create a new question for the new info you need. Otherwise the history is not helpful for other users (question and answer don't match) and you're not giving the user that answered their just rewards...

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Robbie.
I have changed everything back to how it should be.

Comment: Nicely done - thanks. Now post your next question - add the link in here and I'll visit and answer (if I can).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542147/output-google-search-web-results-only-results-using-php

many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you look through the returned json from API? My guess is, that it is completely different, from what you expect

See

> https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list

After clarifiacation, you result is realy different from what your code expected.

Correct code should look like

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[MY API KEY]&cx=[MY CX KEY]&q=lecture';

$body = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($body);
if ($json->items){
   foreach ($json->items as $item){
      print_r($item);
   }
}
```

Comment: I can get the return JSON from API when I go to the URL directly but I'm not quite sure how to grab that data and display it on my page

Comment: can you paste returned JSON somewhere for me to look at?

Comment: As AJAX API is deprecated you can use this GitHub project: https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-php

Comment: this is working fine

Answer (score 4):

You can use the file get content to get the full page content of the google and you can display the result in your site like

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$query = "search term";
$url = 'http://www.google.co.in/search?q='.urlencode($query).'';
$scrape = file_get_contents_curl($url);
```

Comment: If you use the above method to do this, be prepared to get blacklisted by Google rather quickly as this is strictly against their TOS.