# Get more than 8 image search results

Tags: android, google-image-search

I'm using Google image search API in my Android app to search images. It is working fine, but I'm getting only 8 results of query.

How can I get more than 8 images? (Or is there any better way to search images?)

Below is my code:

```
   public class getImagesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
       {
           JSONObject json;
           ProgressDialog dialog;

           @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               super.onPreExecute();

               dialog = ProgressDialog.show(GoogleSearchAPIExampleActivity.this, "", "Please wait...");
           }

           @Override
           protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               URL url;
               try {
                   url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?" +
                    "v=1.0&q="+strSearch+"&rsz=8" ); //&key=ABQIAAAADxhJjHRvoeM2WF3nxP5rCBRcGWwHZ9XQzXD3SWg04vbBlJ3EWxR0b0NVPhZ4xmhQVm3uUBvvRF-VAA&userip=192.168.0.172");

               URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
               connection.addRequestProperty("Referer", "http://technotalkative.com");

               String line;
               StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
               while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                   builder.append(line);
               }

               System.out.println("Builder string => "+builder.toString());

               json = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
               } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
               return null;
           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               super.onPostExecute(result);

               if(dialog.isShowing())
               {
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }

               try {
                   JSONObject responseObject = json.getJSONObject("responseData");
                   JSONArray resultArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("results");

                   listImages = getImageList(resultArray);
                   SetListViewAdapter(listImages);
                   System.out.println("Result array length => "+resultArray.length());
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           }
       }
```

**Logcat:**

```
10 - 22 09: 32: 08.020: I / System.out(2614): Builder string = > {
"responseData": {
    "results": [{
            "GsearchResultClass": "GimageSearch",
            "width": "948",
            "height": "532",
            "imageId": "ANd9GcRjL9QC6U-D2kjCE3NHvmkaDj1U3j46xsqrdsT3xwVkBdcxcV-jakbK2so",
            "tbWidth": "148",
            "tbHeight": "83",
            "unescapedUrl": "http://media.npr.org/assets/img/2013/05/22/ap401533991888_wide-870363ccd3eb24d332ecc17b6bb44a351a5da196-s6-c30.jpg",
            "url": "http://media.npr.org/assets/img/2013/05/22/ap401533991888_wide-870363ccd3eb24d332ecc17b6bb44a351a5da196-s6-c30.jpg",
            "visibleUrl": "www.npr.org",
            "title": "Polio Outbreak In Kenya: \u003cb\u003eA\u003c/b\u003e Threat To Global Eradication : Shots \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
            "titleNoFormatting": "Polio Outbreak In Kenya: A Threat To Global Eradication : Shots ...",
            "originalContextUrl": "http://www.npr.org/blogs/health/2013/05/22/185996377/polio-outbreak-in-kenya-a-threat-to-global-eradication",
            "content": "Polio Outbreak In Kenya: \u003cb\u003eA\u003c/b\u003e Threat To Global Eradication : Shots",
            "contentNoFormatting": "Polio Outbreak In Kenya: A Threat To Global Eradication : Shots",
            "tbUrl": "http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcRjL9QC6U-D2kjCE3NHvmkaDj1U3j46xsqrdsT3xwVkBdcxcV-jakbK2so"
        }, {
            "GsearchResultClass": "GimageSearch",
            "width": "600",
            "height": "424",
            "imageId": "ANd9GcQKbMdb_XZJ1TqEcYBz3TC-psl-NYRwzMzBRDU1tmB8dpUOWlOp0l2IHII",
            "tbWidth": "135",
            "tbHeight": "95",
            "unescapedUrl": "http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2013/05/31/arts/artsspecial/31iht-rfrcballet31A/31iht-rfrcballet31A-articleLarge.jpg",
            "url": "http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2013/05/31/arts/artsspecial/31iht-rfrcballet31A/31iht-rfrcballet31A-articleLarge.jpg",
            "visibleUrl": "www.nytimes.com",
            "title": "\u003cb\u003eA\u003c/b\u003e Fresh Era of Wit and Innovation in Ballet - NYTimes.",
            "titleNoFormatting": "A Fresh Era of Wit and Innovation in Ballet - NYTimes.",
            "originalContextUrl": "http://www.nytimes.com/2013/05/31/arts/artsspecial/A-Fresh-Era-of-Wit-and-Innovation-in-Ballet.html",
            "content": "\u003cb\u003eA\u003c/b\u003e Fresh Era of Wit and Innovation in Ballet - NYTimes.",
            "contentNoFormatting": "A Fresh Era of Wit and Innovation in Ballet - NYTimes.",
            "tbUrl": "http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcQKbMdb_XZJ1TqEcYBz3TC-psl-NYRwzMzBRDU1tmB8dpUOWlOp0l2IHII"
        }, {
            "GsearchResultClass": "GimageSearch",
            "width": "425",
            "height": "283",
            "imageId": "ANd9GcSCIN0Dn0f2rfd-GpdhQ9TuhMt3O0i2X7JKAFSARBFm460PQ1Bd-5eNSsk",
            "tbWidth": "126",
            "tbHeight": "84",
            "unescapedUrl": "http://www.usnews.com/pubdbimages/image/45181/FE_DA_0307_Marine425x283.jpg",
            "url": "http://www.usnews.com/pubdbimages/image/45181/FE_DA_0307_Marine425x283.jpg",
            "visibleUrl": "www.usnews.com",
            "title": "Can Old Marine Strategies Fight \u003cb\u003ea\u003c/b\u003e New Pacific War? - US News and \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
            "titleNoFormatting": "Can Old Marine Strategies Fight a New Pacific War? - US News and ...",
            "originalContextUrl": "http://www.usnews.com/news/articles/2013/03/07/can-old-marine-strategies-fight-a-new-pacific-war",
            "content": "Can Old Marine Strategies Fight \u003cb\u003ea\u003c/b\u003e New Pacific War? - US News and",
            "contentNoFormatting": "Can Old Marine Strategies Fight a New Pacific War? - US News and",
            "tbUrl": "http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q\u003dtbn:ANd9GcSCIN0Dn0f2rfd-GpdhQ9TuhMt3O0i2X7JKAFSARBFm460PQ1Bd-5eNSsk"
        }, {
            "GsearchResultClass": "GimageSearch",
            "width": "460",
            "height": "276",
            "imageId": "ANd9GcTBwAl3G4zqkRw1qx4gMs6gfWfR8YAz-X7HhW6GkfJEBADHDIdDUBpxHhA",
            "tbWidth": "128",
            "tbHeight": "77",
            "unescapedUrl": "http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Arts/Arts_/Pictures/2013/2/12/1360689033304/A-2002-version-of-The-Rit-010.jpg",
            "url": "http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Arts/Arts_/Pictures/2013/2/12/1360689033304/A-2002-version-of-The-Rit-010.jpg",
            "visibleUrl": "www.theguardian.com",
            "title": "The Rite of Spring: \u0026#39;The work of \u003cb\u003ea\u003c/b\u003e madman\u0026#39; | Music | The Guardian",
            "titleNoFormatting": "The Rite of Spring: \u0026#39;The work of a madman\u0026#39; | Music | The Guardian",
            "originalContextUrl": "http://www.theguardian.com/music/2013/feb/12/rite-of-spring-stravinsky",
            "content": "The Rite of Spring: \u00
```

Comment: What does 'rsz=8' mean in url ?

Comment: Number of search results that user wants... means here 8 indicates that maximum 8 search results will be generated. I tried to change that number and tried but it gives only 8 images...

Comment: As you mentioned increasing size does not solve your purpose.Post the complete url and value of string 'strSearch'.

Comment: `rsz` supplies an integer from 1–8 indicating the number of results to return per page.

Comment: @Brontok... I've posted the whole url and here 'strSearch' is the value of edit text, which user inputs to search...

Comment: @ling.s... how can I come to know that my results are more than 8?

Comment: What i mean to say is open your final url in the browser and check the no. of images present in the response. Post the final url after adding the value of editText.

Comment: I'm getting this result...
{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "invalid version", "responseStatus": 400}

Comment: But i'm getting different results in Log cat... see my edited answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?" +
                        "v=1.0&q="+strSearch+"&rsz=8&start=0" );
```

Here you can get 64 image results only using this API.

Now here what happens, if you set start `variable=9`, it will add one more image in output, but the first image will gone (as we can get only 8 images per page).

Now when you set start `variable=8`, you will get next 8 images (page number2 with next 8 images).

Again, if you set start `variable=16`, you will get next 8 images (page number3 with next 8 images).

Again, if you set start `variable=24`, you will get next 8 images (page number4 with next 8 images) and so on.

You will get images till this URL.

```
 url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?" +
                            "v=1.0&q="+strSearch+"&rsz=8&start=56" );
(8th page)
```

Now from here if you increment start variable such as `start=57`, there will be no output.

Answer (score 0):

This service is calling only 8 images. In order to have more than 8 images you need to call this service multiple times.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868815/google-ajax-api-how-do-i-get-more-than-4-results) , This is what you want.