# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined - Google Image API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am trying to generate 5 random images (first row is from flicker and worked ok). On the second row it's from google, but it's only returning 4 for some reason and returning an error on the console that says:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

This is my HTML

```
 <div class="welcomeScreen">
  <form id="players">
    <p>Player 1</p>
    <input id="player1Name" placeholder="Enter player 1's name">

    <div class='player1Info clearfix'>
      <label>
        <img src="">
        <input type='radio' name='player1Avatar' class='player-1-avatar' value=''>
      </label>

      <label>
        <img src="">
        <input type='radio' name='player1Avatar' class='player-1-avatar' value=''>
      </label>

      <label>
        <img src="">
        <input type='radio' name='player1Avatar' class='player-1-avatar' value=''>
      </label>

      <label>
        <img src="">
        <input type='radio' name='player1Avatar' class='player-1-avatar' value=''>
      </label>

      <label>
        <img src="">
        <input type='radio' name='player1Avatar' class='player-1-avatar' value=''>
      </label>
    </div>

    <p>Player 2</p>
    <input id="player2Name" placeholder="Enter player 2's name">

    <div class='player2Info clearfix'>
      <label>
        <img src="">
        <input type='radio' name='player2Avatar' class='player-2-avatar' value=''>
      </label>

      <label>
        <img src="">
        <input type='radio' name='player2Avatar' class='player-2-avatar' value=''>
      </label>

      <label>
        <img src="">
        <input type='radio' name='player2Avatar' class='player-2-avatar' value=''>
      </label>

      <label>
        <img src="">
        <input type='radio' name='player2Avatar' class='player-2-avatar' value=''>
      </label>

      <label>
        <img src="">
        <input type='radio' name='player2Avatar' class='player-2-avatar' value=''>
      </label>
    </div>

    <input value="Start the race!" type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function buildFlickrUrl(p) {
    var url = "https://farm";
    url += p.farm;
    url += ".staticflickr.com/";
    url += p.server;
    url += "/";
    url += p.id;
    url += "_";
    url += p.secret;
    url += ".jpg";

    return url;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    var flickrUrl = "https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?    
    method=flickr.photos.search&format=json&api_key=
    4ef070a1a5e8d5fd19faf868213c8bd0&nojsoncallback=1&text=dog

    $.get(flickrUrl, function(response) { 
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var photoUrl = buildFlickrUrl(response.photos.photo[i]);
            $(".player1Info label img").eq(i).attr('src', photoUrl);
            $(".player1 img").eq(i).attr('src' , photoUrl);
            console.log(photoUrl);
        }
    });

var input="cute kitten";

$.getJSON("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?callback=?", {
    q: input,
    v: '1.0'
},
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: clearly `data.responseData.results[i]` doesn't have a `url` property, so you have to console.log `data` and see what you've really got.

Comment: Looking in the network tab for the google request, the data retrieved only brings in 4 images, there is no 5th image

Comment: error means `data.responseData.results[i]` is undefined

Comment: @PatrickEvans  does `for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)`  not return 5 images?

Comment: Your for loop is setup to go from 0 to 4 (i<5), 0,1,2,3,4 <- how many is there: 5, so your loop executes that many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a breakpoint in the console and look at the results being returned.

```
> data.responseData.results
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

You will see the results has a length of 4 and you are looping to read index of 4.

Change

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
```

to

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.responseData.results.length; i++) {
```

Comment: I'd reccommend `data.responseData.results.forEach(...`

Comment: http://oi62.tinypic.com/25yvedx.jpg 
This is what I get. So `for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)` doesn't call 5 items?

Comment: I know that is the error you got...Click on the error and it takes you right to the line I changed.

Comment: @KenRyan It does call 5 times, the 5th iteration through the loop is what causes the error

Comment: @epascarello that worked!
however, it still calls for only 4 images for some reason, I went to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=cute%20kitten to see how it's set up and it only calls for 4 it seems?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868815/google-ajax-api-how-do-i-get-more-than-4-results

Answer (score 1):

Your response data is ok, the problem is in your `for` loop.

The object `data.responseData.results` contains 4 elements and your looping since **i < 5**. Just change it to `data.responseData.results.length`.

```
 for(var i = 0; i < data.responseData.results.length ; i++) {
    var googleImageUrl = data.responseData.results[i].url;
    $(".player2Info label img").eq(i).attr('src', data.responseData.results[i].url);
    console.log(googleImageUrl);
  }
```

Comment: thank you! That got rid of the error. It still is only drawing 4 images though. I checked https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=cute%20kitten  and it seems there are only 4 images at the top... how can I get a fifth?